# como puedo reeplazar los if?

Tags: javascript, html, desarrollo

Hola como están? quisiera saber si no hay alguna forma de reeplazar mis if  para que le codigo no quede tan extenso. Pensé en un operado logico, pero nosé si es lo correcto. ㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤ

```js
[
{
        nombre: "Coco",
        categoria: "Infantil",
        plataforma: "./img/disney-plus-logo.png",
        descripcion: "Miguel es un niño que sueña con ser músico, pero su familia se lo prohíbe porque su tatarabuelo, músico, los abandonó Por accidente, Miguel entra en la Tierra de los Muertos, de donde sólo podrá salir si un familiar difunto le concede su bendición.",
        imagen: "./img/coco.jpg",
        id: 4,
    },
    {
        nombre: "Garra",
        categoria: "Drama",
        plataforma: "./img/netflix.png",
        descripcion: "Cuando un desafortunado cazatalentos de básquetbol encuentra un jugador excepcional en España, se dispone a demostrar que pueden triunfar en la NBA.",
        imagen: "./img/garra.jpg",
        id: 5,
    },]
peliculas.forEach((peli) => {
                document.getElementById(peli.id).addEventListener('click', () => {
                  
                  if (peli.plataforma === "./img/netflix.png") {
                      location.href = "https://www.netflix.com/"
                    }
                    if (peli.plataforma === "./img/disney-plus-logo.png") {
                        location.href = "https://www.disneyplus.com/"
                    }
                    if (peli.plataforma === "./img/HBO-Max-Logo.png") {
                        location.href = "https://play.hbomax.com/"
                    }
                    if (peli.plataforma === "./img/paramount-plus-logo.png") {
                        location.href = "https://www.paramountplus.com/"
                    }
                    localStorage.setItem(" ", JSON.stringify(peli.nombre))
                })
            })`
```

Answer (score 3):

Puedes expresarlo en un objeto, así te ahorras los `if`.

Por ejemplo:

```
var url = {
  "./img/netflix.png": "https://www.netflix.com/",
  "./img/disney-plus-logo.png": "https://www.disneyplus.com/",
  "./img/HBO-Max-Logo.png": "https://play.hbomax.com/",
  "./img/paramount-plus-logo.png": "https://www.paramountplus.com/"
};
```

Luego, sólo te preocupas por buscar el valor asociado a cada key, veamos un ejemplo:

```js
var url = {
  "./img/netflix.png": "https://www.netflix.com/",
  "./img/disney-plus-logo.png": "https://www.disneyplus.com/",
  "./img/HBO-Max-Logo.png": "https://play.hbomax.com/",
  "./img/paramount-plus-logo.png": "https://www.paramountplus.com/"
};

/*Creamos un objeto de prueba a mano*/
var peli = {
  plataforma: "./img/HBO-Max-Logo.png"
};

console.log(url[peli.plataforma])
```

En el contexto de tu código, sólo tendrías que hacer esto:

```
peliculas.forEach((peli) => {
document.getElementById(peli.id).addEventListener('click', () => {
        location.href = url[peli.plataforma];
        localStorage.setItem(" ", JSON.stringify(peli.nombre))
    })
})
```

Lo extraño es que tu objeto `peli` no tenga una propiedad `url` también, algo así:

```
{
        nombre: "Coco",
        categoria: "Infantil",
        plataforma: "./img/disney-plus-logo.png",
        url: "https://www.disneyplus.com/",
        descripcion: "Miguel es un niño que sueña con ser músico, pero su familia se lo prohíbe porque su tatarabuelo, músico, los abandonó Por accidente, Miguel entra en la Tierra de los Muertos, de donde sólo podrá salir si un familiar difunto le concede su bendición.",
        imagen: "./img/coco.jpg",
        id: 4,
    },
```

En cuyo caso podrás acceder a la `url` directamente mediante: `peli.url`, y en el contexto del código esto bastaría, sin necesidad de crear un objeto adicional: `location.href = peli.url;`

Answer (score 0):

Si usas python 3.10 podes usar "match" que es como el "switch" de js.
Te dejo un ejemplo de la documentacion.

```
def http_error(status):
    match status:
        case 400:
            return "Bad request"
        case 404:
            return "Not found"
        case 418:
            return "I'm a teapot"
        case _:
            return "Something's wrong with the internet"
```

https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.10.html

Comment: genial, Gracias a todos!